# Next-Auth: creating session / jwt manually after payment received

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

We don't want to force users to signup at our (Next) application to buy some content. Since our payment provider is returning all needed information, we can create user and account objects using our adapter after a payment has been received.

How can we use Next-auth to **login** that user right away (their email address is verified thanks to paypal)? Put differently: How can we create a JWT / session manually when a payment has been received and we know which user to authenticate?

Comment: My solution ended up just being to use the Credentials Provider. You could maybe pass the email after the payment is complete via a query string to a "success" page, and then call the next-auth signIn() function and pass the data you want. https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials